# Counting problem: proving

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider an antireflexive, symmetric relation "is a friend of". Proof that in a group of $n$ people, there will always be an even number of people with an odd number of friends.

What I've already tried:

Suppose $A$ is the set of people with $|A| = n$. Consider the function $f: A \to \mathbb{N}_{<n}$ that maps a person to the number of friends he/she has ($<n$ because the relation we're looking at is antireflexive). The codomain of $f$ has exactly $n$ elements. $A$ and $\mathbb{N}_{<n}$ have the same number of elements and therefor we can always find a bijection, and thus a surjection, between the two sets. If $n$ is even, we can map all people to $n-1$, meaning everybody is everybody's friend. If $n$ is odd, we randomly take $(n-1)/2$ people and map them to $n-2$; the other half of the people can be mapped to $0$. This completes the proof.

I don't know if this is the correct way of proving these type of questions. Does anyone have other methods/ideas? Is my proof correct?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a graph theory problem.

Comment: handshaking lemma is not it?

Comment: You seem to be deciding who should be friends with each other. You should accept that they have already decided who are friends already.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $v_k$ denote a person observe that the total number of 'is friend of' is **even** because $v_x$ 'is friend of' $v_y$ implies the converse too. So now if number of people with odd number of friend is *odd* the "the total number of 'is friend of'" would be odd too hence *contradiction* which proves the assertion (you may also refer Wikipedia "handshaking lemma " for general graph theoretic proof)

Answer (score 0):

Assume there are an odd number of people with an odd number of friends. Then the total number of friendship is $\frac{\text{odd*odd+even*even}}{2}$ which is not an integer. This is a contradiction.